# JSON deserialisation object disposal

Tags: jade-platform

I have some code like this:

```
vars
  json: JadeJson;
  objs: ObjectArray;
  foo: Foo;
begin
  create json transient;
  create objs transient;
  foo := json.parse(response, Foo, objs).Foo;
  // Do something with foo
epilog
  delete json;
  delete objs;
end;
```

Is foo deleted by the call to delete objs, or do I need to dispose of it (any any other object stored in objs) separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation doesn't specify for the return value, but for the createdObjects parameter it says "It is the responsibility of the caller to delete all objects returned from the method." so I would think it doesn't get deleted automatically.

You could test this by storing a reference to foo somewhere and after the method returns check to see if it's a valid object reference.

Comment: Yeah, you have to delete foo yourself.